# Drupal 7 inserting space before inline HTML tags upon rendering

Tags: input-formats, theming

Whenever I try to use `<a>`, `<em>`, `<sup>`, or `<sub>` tags (or probably any other inline tag), Drupal inserts a space before the HTML tag. This does not happen within the node but rather upon the HTML rendering.

For instance:

`234<sup>2</sup>` in the body field

is rendered as

`234 <sup>2</sup>` on the page

Any idea why this would be or what I can do to eliminate the space that is being added? I have TinyMCE installed on the site, but (long story) it is disabled so that I input everything in raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Full HTML" text input rather than "Filtered HTML", then Drupal won't parse or modify your markup.

Comment: It's adding the space regardless of whether I have chosen Full HTML.

Comment: Are you sure that output isn't cached? View the page with an argument to break the cache, like ?asdf at the end of the URL. If it isn't cached, something else must be acting on it, maybe in the theme? I just tested this on a standard Drupal 7.23 site with Bartik and was unable to replicate the behavior you've described.

Comment: Tried adding ?asdf, and the space is still inserted. Not sure what's going on. It's not the theme, because it's an actual space that I can select individually. Might have to take a look at modules I guess.

Comment: The space is visible when you view the page source, not just inspect the element?

Comment: That's correct. When I look at the Body from the Edit screen, it looks just how I want it. But when I view the page source from the rendered page, there is a space. Weird, I know.

Comment: Try changing the theme to Bartik? Obviously not the solution, but will eliminate a possibility.

Comment: I'd rather not take the site offline to try that, as I'm working on a live site.

Comment: You don't have a dev or test environment? :-(

Comment: Nope. I've never used one.